# python regular-expression "`(``|[^`])*`" ，The result is different from what I thought

Tags: python

I encountered a problem while using regular expression parsing.

```
import re
a_re = r"`(``|[^`])*`"
a_str = '`abc`12`cde`45'
b = re.findall(a_re,a_str)
print(b) # ['c', 'e']
```

Why did this result occur?

I tried other rules again

```
import re
a_re = r"`(ab|[^c])*`"
a_str = '`ab`1`df`'
b = re.findall(a_re,a_str)
print(b) # ['f']
```

I'm even more confused

Comment: Did you look at a [regex explainer](https://regex101.com/r/gKmYOT/1)? Also please don't trample other people's edits.

Comment: "Why did this result occur?" You first: **what do you think the result should be instead**? Step by step, **what is your reasoning** to get this result?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> The result depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern. If there are no groups, return a list of strings matching the whole pattern. **If there is exactly one group, return a list of strings matching that group.**

The final value of a capturing group is the *last* substring it matched in the overall match, e.g. if ``` (``|[^`])* ``` matched `abc` then ``` (``|[^`]) ``` captures `c`.

`re.findall`’s API is badly designed; I recommend you use alternative functions, like [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), instead.

```
import re
a_re = r"`((``|[^`])*)`"
a_str = '`abc`12`cde`45'
b = [m.group(1).replace("``", "`") for m in re.finditer(a_re, a_str)]
print(b)  # ['abc', 'cde']
```